# pthread_join function crash

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

There is a crash inside 'pthread_join' when main function calls it and before that the child thread already terminated. This is the backtrace from gdb:

```
Core was generated by `./bin/test'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb76fb530 in __call_tls_dtors@plt () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb76fb530 in __call_tls_dtors@plt () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb76fdd5a in start_thread (arg=0xb40fab40) at pthread_create.c:319
#2  0xb762f74e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129
```

The pthread activation function receives NULL argument and return NULL argument. I am clueless why I am seeing this crash consistently.

Could somebody help what could be wrong in child thread activation function? I am using Fedora 20 and gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC)

Skeleton of child activation function is below

```
void* testControl(void* param)
{
   ...................
   return NULL;
}
```

As the my code is huge I am giving here the code snippet which explains how I am creating child threads, their exits and termination.

```
unsigned long int rcThId1;  
unsigned long int rcThId2;
unsigned long int rcThId3;
unsigned long int rcThId4;
unsigned long int rcThId5;
unsigned long int rcThId6;

void* rcControl1(void* arg)
{
  bool th_loop = true;

  while(th_loop)
  {

     /*Listen and receive the message on message queue*/

     ...........
     ..........

     switch(message_type)
     {
        ............
        ............

        case EXIT:

          th_loop = false;
          break;

        default:
          break;
     }

   }

   return NULL;

}

/*Activation functions for rcControl2 rcControl3 rcControl4

rcControl5 rcControl6 similar to the defination of rcControl1*/

int main(void)
{
  pthread_create(&rcThId1,NULL,rcControl1,NULL);
  pthread_create(&rcThId2,NULL,rcControl2,NULL);
  pthread_create(&rcThId3,NULL,rcControl3,NULL);
  pthread_create(&rcThId4,NULL,rcControl4,NULL);
  pthread_create(&rcThId5,NULL,rcControl5,NULL);
  pthread_create(&rcThId6,NULL,rcControl6,NULL);

  ..............
  ..............
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread1*/
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread2*/
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread3*/
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread4*/
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread5*/
  /*Post EXIT event to Thread6*/
  /*By now all threads would have already exited */

  pthread_join(rcThId1, NULL);/*Inside this function crash is happening*/    
  pthread_join(rcThId2, NULL);
  pthread_join(rcThId3, NULL);
  pthread_join(rcThId4, NULL);
  pthread_join(rcThId5, NULL);
  pthread_join(rcThId6, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Inside `pthread_join(rcThId1, NULL);` call the crash is happened.

Thanks

Comment: how do you call `pthread_join`?

Comment: I have faced similar behavior when the pthreads were wrapped by a class, and the class' method which invokes pthread_join was called out after the class instance was being destructed. Perhaps you can somehow check same in your case.

Comment: Post the code at least

Comment: `__call_tls_dtors` siggests thread have finished and tries to destroy its TLS. Is there anything interesting/dangerous that is kept in TLS?

Comment: As the code is huge, I am giving here my code snippet which explain how I am creating child threads, their exits and joining them.

Answer (score 0):

In the (pseudo)code you posted, the main issue is the type of thread identifiers: they all should be of type `pthread_t`. But you have `unsigned long int`s. The crash is most likely because `pthread_join()` attempts to read `rcThId1` et al as if they are `pthread_t` which they are not.

Change the type of `rcThId1` ..`rcThId6` to `pthread_t`.

You should be getting some warnings. If not compiler with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
```

Aside:

You probably need to have th thread ids as global. Move them inside `main()` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I have changed declaration of 'thread Id' from 'unsigned long int' to 'pthread_t' but still the result is same. The thread Ids already global as they defined outside the main function.

Comment: There's not much in the code you posted. Otherwise, create an [MCvE]. Did you check `pthread_create()` calls succeed?

Comment: Surprisingly if I replace 'return NULL' with 'pthread_exit(0)', no crash in pthread_join and program executed successfully. Confused why 'return NULL' causing crash and 'pthread_exit' not.

Comment: Yes, pthread_create() was successful and the activation function was also executed for some time before it exit.

Comment: It sounds like you have some *undefined behaviour* (buffer overrun, uninitialized pointer use etc etc) in your code. Because return NULL; wouldn't change anything if you use it in place of pthread_exit(0); -- both are equivalent. I can't really help much as the code you posted is too abstract and doesn't exhibit the *actual* problem you have.

Comment: I think the entry and return arguments matters to pthread and inside activation function, does it matter how I written the code especially when it is returning NULL? If I have programming bugs in my activation function on how I use variables, how I declared them, how memory is allocated , whether memory freed or not, is it matters at thread exit ?

Comment: Typically memory leaks don't matter. But if you have buffer overruns etc, then it's most definitely going to show up in an unexpected way (which looks to be the case here because replacing replacing `return NULL;` "fixes" the issue).

Comment: Actually I integrated third party code with my program and in the third party code there were optional assembly instructions for performance reasons based on compiler and word width of the OS. This piece of code was working well when I was using fedora 18 and the problem occurred when i started using Fedora 20 which has different gcc compiler version. Due to compiler mismatch looks like the assembler instructions were behaving differently. Now after disabling optional assembler instructions, pthread_join has no issue. Thanks everybody for your comments.